# PHP Getting imap open to work

Tags: php, cakephp, imap, gmail-imap

I just moved my app to the cloud hosting. I was using imap_open to access mails in my gmail account. It worked fine.

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = '...@gmail.com';
$password = '****';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

Now I get an error **Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1176 >= 1024)** Does anybody have any idea about this error. I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Likely a bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=548857

Comment: @Jack is there a bug in my code. Or is it on the server. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's a bug in your code. It looks fine. When you read the bug report you will see that PHP links against a library with a known issue (lib-c client).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've hit the maximum amount of open file descriptors.  Maybe restarting your system?